# Excel Macro with parameters not found

Tags: excel, vba, parameters

I have a macro that I created. A command button is clicked and its code passes a worksheet as an argument into a public sub. However, Excel crashed and closed the editor. When I reopened it, I can't find my code ANYWHERE. It still obviously exists somewhere, because when I click on the button the code still completely executes. But it doesn't show up on the macro list because it has parameters and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to be able to edit it now.

Comment: Try going to where the code should be, then at the top, click Window >> Cascade  --- Does it show then?

Comment: Tried that. It just has the one window containing code for the command button.

Comment: put a breakpoint on the code you CAN see, then use F8 to step thru it

Comment: What type of button is it (Forms/ActiveX) ?

Comment: @braX you're a beautiful human being. Breakpoint on the line that called the sub, pressed F8 and appeared my box. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Put a breakpoint on the code you CAN see, then when it stops, click debug, then use F8 to step thru it